# Viewing REQUEST object in IE with Developer Tool Bar

Tags: internet-explorer, ie-developer-tools

Is it possible? If so, how? If not, what do I need to do to see the REQUEST object (POST and GET vars) in IE?

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use Network Capture tab in the Developer Tools (Press F12 to open it), but it is only available in IE9 I believe (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/marcelolr/archive/2011/06/15/network-capture-with-internet-explorer.aspx).

I if you need to capture requests in other versions of IE, the best solution is to use Fiddler (http://www.fiddler2.com)

Comment: Probably best to just use Fiddler.

Comment: Confirmed you can use this tab in IE9 to catch ajax/post/get calls.  I use web console and firebug all the time in FF, but find IE developer tools cumbersome.

Answer (score 2):

To start capturing network traffic in Internet Explorer 9+, press <kbd>F12</kbd> to open the Developer Tools, click the Network tab, and then click the **Start Capturing** button (or a green triangle with a tooltip **Enable network traffic capturing**).

[image: IE 11 dev tools]

To see information about a specific request, select an entry in the summary view, and then click the **Go To Detailed View** button (or just **DETAILS**).

[image: IE 11 dev tools]

You can find here Request Headers, Request Body, and so on.

To stop the capturing click a red square.

---

References:

1. [Using Windows Internet Explorer Developer Tools Network Capture | MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg130952(v=vs.85).aspx).